# Is it possible to display copies in document library column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, send-to-destination

We are using SharePoint Online with Office 365.
When you make a copy using the Send To... / Copy command you can display the Copy source in the target library in a column.
Is there any way to display if a document has any copies in another location? I mean in the "origin" document library have a column to show if a connected copy exists.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not by Default, because it is saved in the "copied" item. The source-item doesn´t know if it is copied (btw. it coudld even be copied multiple times).

Comment: Thank you! If it is not possible by default, is there any workaround? I only need to indicate if (one or more) copies exist or not.

Comment: As your platform is SharepointOnline, the only Option is to include a Javascript on the page which adds the requested Information using the Javascript Clientobjectmodel.